# Move Sign in section under search button

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, header

I have Magento 2.1.4 and I want to remove entirely the top block and move the Sign in and create account links below the search bar.

How can I do that?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to move sign in section under the search button

```
<move element="header.links" destination="top.search" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code in body of file /Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="header.panel" remove="true"/> 
<move element="header.links" destination="top.search" />
```

I hope this will help you.